Recoger el valor de un input text con javascript
Quiero recoger el numero que el usuario introducira en el campo buscar para despues pasarlo como variable en el img src y asi preseleccionar la imagen que el usuario quiera.
Ahora casi lo tengo pero estoy haciendo cambios y queria preguntar a la comunidad antes de estropear mas en vez de arreglar.
En el codigo aparece la funcion buscar que dispone de una variable codigo que sera un numero entre 1 y 400 y determinara la pagina que queremos leer. Para ello primero quiero conseguir ese numero pero no consigo que el parametro sea visible.
index.html


/*Cargador de eventos al iniciar la página*/
window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, false);

/*Contador inicializado en cero*/
var contador = 0;

function iniciar() {
  setInterval('cambiarImg()', 750000);
}

var obj = document.getElementById('slider');
var obj2 = obj.getElementsByTagName('img');

function cambiarManual(sentido) {
  if (sentido == "DER") {
    obj2[contador].style.opacity = 0;
    if (contador < obj2.length - 1) {
      contador++;
      obj2[contador].style.opacity = 1;
      console.log('Contador vale ' + contador + ' Longitud ' + obj2.length);
    } else {
      contador = 0;
      obj2[contador].style.opacity = 1;
      console.log('Contador vale ' + contador + ' Longitud ' + obj2.length);
    }
  } else if (sentido == "IZQ") {
    obj2[contador].style.opacity = 0;
    if (contador != 0) {
      contador--;
      obj2[contador].style.opacity = 1;
    } else {
      contador = obj2.length - 1;
      obj2[contador].style.opacity = 1;
    }
  }
}

function buscar() {
  var pagina;
  pagina = document.getElementById('buscar');
  alert("Entra" + pagina);

}

function cambiarImg() {

  if (contador == obj2.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj2.length; i++) {
      obj2[i].style.opacity = '0';
      contador--;
    }
    obj2[contador].style.opacity = '1';
  } else {
    obj2[contador].style.opacity = '1';
    contador++;
  }

}
<div id="slider">
  <img src="img/pagina_1.webp" alt="">
  <img src="img/pagina_2.webp" alt="">
  <img src="img/pagina_3.webp" alt="">
  <img src="img/pagina_4.webp" alt="">
  <img src="img/pagina_5.webp" alt="">
  <img src="img/pagina_6.webp" alt="">



  <img src="img/pagina_427.webp" alt="">
  <img src="img/pagina_428.webp" alt="">
  <img src="img/pagina_429.webp" alt="">
  <img src="img/pagina_430.webp" alt="">
  <img src="img/pagina_431.webp" alt="">
  <img src="img/pagina_432.webp" alt="">
  <img src="img/pagina_433.webp" alt="">
  <img src="img/pagina_434.webp" alt=""></div>


<table border="1">




  <td id="izquierda">
    <input type="button" value="anterior" onclick="cambiarManual('IZQ')">
  </td>
  <td id="derecha">
    <input type="button" value="siguiente" onclick="cambiarManual('DER')">
  </td>
  <td id="buscar">
    <form name="form" action="index.html" method="get">

      <input type="text" id="buscar">
      <button onsubmit="buscar()">Buscar</button>
    </form>



</table>




¿Y si pruebas con value? Es decir, pagina=document.getElementById('buscar').value;

Tampoco funciona pero no salta el alert, por lo tanto es que no esta entrando a la funcion buscar. Me he dado cuenta que la variable contador, si guarda un registro de lo que quiero, lo que pasa que ahora tengo que concatenar en el html y la forma que he pensado no me suena.  



@AlfonsoSandroGómezGómez actualicé mi respuesta para reflejar qué es lo que causa que la función no se llame y cómo solucionarlo.

El problema es que el código HTML es incorrecto. Entre otros errores, tienes dos elementos con id "buscar", la celda de la tabla y el campo de tipo texto:
 <td id="buscar">
   <form name ="form" action="index.html" method="get">
     <input type="text" id="buscar"  >
     <button onsubmit="buscar()">Buscar</button>
   </form>

Cuando realizas document.getElementById('buscar'), el navegador te va a devolver el primero que encuentre en el código que es el <td> y no el <input> que es el que quieres para leer el valor.
La solución sería asegurarte que no hay IDs repetidos en el HTML y, a partir de ahí, ya puedes leer el valor sin problemas usando document.getElementById('buscar').value.
 <td id="td-buscar">
   <form name ="form" action="index.html" method="get">
     <input type="text" id="buscar"  >
     <button onsubmit="buscar()">Buscar</button>
   </form>


Otro problema importante es que estás poniendo el onsubmit en el botón. Pero un botón no tiene evento submit. Es el formulario el que lo tiene. Mueve el onsubmit a la etiqueta form.
Y también otro problema: la función tiene el mismo nombre que el id de un elemento en la página web. Entonces el navegador va a intentar ejecutar la función buscar pero lo que encuentra es un elemento HTML. Cambia el nombre de la función para que sea único, por ejemplo a buscador():


/*Cargador de eventos al iniciar la página*/
window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, false);

/*Contador inicializado en cero*/
var contador = 0;

function iniciar() {
  setInterval('cambiarImg()', 750000);
}

var obj = document.getElementById('slider');
var obj2 = obj.getElementsByTagName('img');

function cambiarManual(sentido) {
  if (sentido == "DER") {
    obj2[contador].style.opacity = 0;
    if (contador < obj2.length - 1) {
      contador++;
      obj2[contador].style.opacity = 1;
      console.log('Contador vale ' + contador + ' Longitud ' + obj2.length);
    } else {
      contador = 0;
      obj2[contador].style.opacity = 1;
      console.log('Contador vale ' + contador + ' Longitud ' + obj2.length);
    }
  } else if (sentido == "IZQ") {
    obj2[contador].style.opacity = 0;
    if (contador != 0) {
      contador--;
      obj2[contador].style.opacity = 1;
    } else {
      contador = obj2.length - 1;
      obj2[contador].style.opacity = 1;
    }
  }
}

function buscador() {
  var pagina;
  pagina = document.getElementById('buscar');
  alert("Entra" + pagina);

}

function cambiarImg() {

  if (contador == obj2.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj2.length; i++) {
      obj2[i].style.opacity = '0';
      contador--;
    }
    obj2[contador].style.opacity = '1';
  } else {
    obj2[contador].style.opacity = '1';
    contador++;
  }

}
<div id="slider">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""></div>


<table border="1">




  <td id="izquierda">
    <input type="button" value="anterior" onclick="cambiarManual('IZQ')">
  </td>
  <td id="derecha">
    <input type="button" value="siguiente" onclick="cambiarManual('DER')">
  </td>
  <td id="td-buscar">
    <form name="form" action="index.html" method="get"  onsubmit="buscador()">

      <input type="text" id="buscar">
      <button>Buscar</button>
    </form>



</table>




Muchas gracias. Con esta respuesta podre seguir adelante unos pasos.
